# Are cursives and circle polygons, or two other different things?

Tags: terminology, circles, plane-geometry, polygons

I understand that any polygon always contain three or more [points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(geometry)) (translated in Hebrew "dots", hence my previous confusion and deleted question), but never two points, because a geometric [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) (translated in Hebrew as "shape", hence my previous confusion and deleted question) with only two dots, is only a [line segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment).

### My problem

With this understanding, I am in problem about how to define cursive shapes (such as the letters `C` or `O` that I used here to represent a *perfect half circle* and a *perfect circle* although they aren't), let alone a real perfect circle (which I understand to have a "world of its own" in mathematics).

### My question

Are cursives and circle polygons, or two other different things (and possibly different from one another)?
<sub>(In first glimpse I thought "maybe a cursive is a line segment?")</sub>

Comment: A first answer is that they are different from the point of view of toplogy.

Comment: IMO, *cursive* shapes is misleading. It essentially denotes handwritten characters as opposed to printed ones. Both are *curvilinear*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polygons are made of straight line segments.

You may generalize the concept by admitting curved edges; that might be called *curvilinear* polygons.

A circle is a circle. A closed, convex curve without angular points may be called an *oval*.

The portion of a straight line between two points is a segment. The portion of a curve between two points is an *arc*.

---

Circles are the only curves with a constant curvature, i.e. that can "slide on themselves". There are millions other types of curves obtained from analytical equations.

In the computerized typesetting systems, the curves are usually built from conics and parametric cubics (such as the well-known Bezier curves).

[image]

Comment: Hello Yves Daoust; I tried to read your answer several times; I recently found the one thing I miss in it and tried to improve it by suggesting an edit. Please go through my last edit suggestion and it's edit summary to understand what I missed and how the answer might be changed to be a bit more helpful, in that context.

Comment: Hello again, I just saw the edit was rejected, perhaps before you even had a notification about it (which was since then deleted), but here is a link to it if you haven't seen it: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1319742

Comment: @JohnDoea: yes, I saw this. IMO this hair cutting about the number of geometric primitives is irrelevant to my answer.

Comment: Yves, thanks, my only problem is understanding what is common between you guys mathematicians; it's important to me to know what I described in the edit is a correct.

Comment: I have just published a new question about this - perhaps you'd like to explain this there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3539026/why-isnt-a-line-segment-considered-a-polygon-by-mathematicians

Answer (score 0):

Polygons are vertices joined by (straight) line segments.

Circles are, well, circular.
They are the set of points equidistant from the circle's center.

Of course, these are different shapes.
And there are other shapes as well.
If you take a pencil and draw some curve-y (closed?) line on a sheet of paper, chances are it won't be a circle.
You might draw, say, an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse), a [lemniscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate) or something else entirely.
Most things don't even have names!