# Why isn't a line segment considered a "polygon" by mathematicians?

Tags: terminology, plane-geometry, polygons

I understand that *polygons* are defined by generally all mathematicians as:

> Made of three or more straight line segments.

But, two line segments forming a line are also a "poly" of a "gons" due to not having just one segment.

So, I intuitively I as a non mathematician understand simple line segments with "more than one" gon/segment as a "polygon".

**Why isn't a line segment considered a "polygon" by mathematicians?**

Comment: Polygons of two sides are uninteresting.

Comment: For some I guess, but what is "really true" here, that's what I'm out for...

Comment: How do you define "really" ?

Comment: At least for now I would say, shortly: "Physical objects and conscious agents with the ability to connect and love with many private cases, **at least**". we humans interpret that species-specifically by our brains (with other brains we might have interpret a "triangle" as a "square" and so forth; I wonder what is deemed "real" by mathematicians in this context.

Comment: Some intuitive topological properties of polygons are that (a) there are as many edges as vertices, (b) each vertex is of degree 2, and (c) the shape is connected. You may not want to lose these

Comment: You don't answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't understand why you said that. I know of nothing "real" besides physical object and set of consciousnesses (interpreting physical object per organismic capabilities).

Comment: Arguing with definitions isn't usually very productive :) This is kind of similar to asking "why isn't $1$ a prime number". That's just because it's not as useful to define it that way. As for metaphysical speculation about whether triangles are actually squares, that's not something mathematicians care about. We make definitions and state axioms and explore their consequences.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I think I didn't argue anything as I am just trying to understand the consensus...

Comment: @JohnDoea: I sometimes have use for "bi-gons", polygons with two vertices and two (coincident) edges ... effectively a "double-segment". I also sometimes have use for "polygons" that aren't convex, could have coincident vertices and self-intersecting edges, and may be non-planar. In any case, be careful about what you ascribe to "all mathematicians".

Comment: One line segment is usually a "polygonal path", even if it's usually not a "polygon".

Comment: Connecting (4,3,2) equispaced points on a circle makes for a (square, equilateral triangle, diangle" ) respectively. The diangle has *two* sides. The corner angle is zero, also confirmed by case n=2 internal angle zero sum $(2n-4)\pi/2$. The word "gon" means angle, (Sanskrit) has the sharpest angle like a needle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the definition of the polygon, you will find your answer.

> **Definition:** A polygon is a **closed** figure where the sides are all line segments. Each side must **intersect exactly two others** sides but only at their endpoints. The sides must be noncollinear and have a common endpoint.

**Note:** A circle is not a polygon as it does not have straight sides.

Comment: Hi ; thanks ; I understand from that that only 4 line segments up are polygons, so "simple" line segments and triangles aren't ; have I missed anything?...

Comment: This is the definition of a *simple polygon* with vertices in general position. Other definitions exist.

Comment: @JohnDoea. Triangle is a polygon and also it comply my given definition.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Can you please clear your point, I am unable to get it.

Comment: @nmasanta thx ; sorry, I confused a triangle with a caret `^`.

Comment: Isn't caret an "interesting" polygon for you @YvesDaoust ?...

Comment: @JohnDoea: for geometry, no. For computational geometry, maybe.